# AWS EB CLI Apache

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

Where do you select Apache as the proxy server when creating/deploying from the EB CLI ? I can't seem to find the right command to set the proxy server as apache. It seem to keep wanting to use nginx instead

Answer (score 0):

You set it using [.ebextensions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/ebextensions.html) option [aws:elasticbeanstalk:environment:proxy](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/command-options-specific.html). Not all environments support it , so you have to make sure that you use the one which supports it (e.g. php).

In the [AWS CLI](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/elasticbeanstalk/create-environment.html) you have `--option-settings` to set up those options.